# how to make python coding to deployable installer or exe file

Tags: python, makefile, exe

I am Shin, from South Korea. 
I am very new to programming. 
is there anyway to change my python code to deployable installer or exe file.
(what I mean is a program installer that has UI 
which make anyone can run my code by just input somethings and clicking. like normal program as we see in our computer. this might not be proper translation...)

Please give me some link that explain how to. I couldn't find any.

not pyinstaller... I want to make my code to proper program. 
or, does I need to covert my all code to exe by pyinstaller 
than make it to proper program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shin, try Autopy to EXE. This should solve your problem.

https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/